# Show/Hide shipping method if billing state equals to store state location

Tags: woocommerce, shipping-method

I have a restaurant site,i am setting up the shipping costs, what i need is that if the customer billing state is equal to the store state it display a low flat rate= 2.50 which is the minimun, and if not not equal do not show low flate rate. keeping low flat rate hidden by default.

i have multiple flate rates based on groups and all i need is to show low flat rate if billing state is equal to the store state.

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'custom_woocommerce_states' );

  function custom_woocommerce_states( $states ) {

  $states['PA'] = array(
'PA1' => 'Villa lucre ', 
'PA2' => 'crisol',
  'PA3' => 'brisas del golf',
      'PA4' => 'cerro viento', 
    'PA5' => 'San Antonio',
  'PA6' => 'campo limbergh ', 
'PA7' => 'Juan Díaz',
  'PA8' => 'Concepción',
      'PA9' => 'Pedregal', 



);

return $states;
}
```

this is how i created the billing state and the store city location as well, meaning the restaurant name is "seafood" location form a dropbox San Antonio, if the customer billing state select San Antonio then show low flate rate.

I was searching but with no luck how to show store state location on cart and checkout page  so i can compare and do as request but i could'n

Answer (score 1):

if in case anyone needs to do this or something similar here is the answer

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_package_rates','show_hide_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
 function show_hide_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
    $store_state        = WC()->countries->get_base_state();
    $chosen_billing_state = WC()->customer->get_billing_state();
if(   $store_state    != $chosen_billing_state  ){
    unset($rates['flat_rate:1']);
    unset($rates['flat_rate:4']);
}

return $rates;
 }
```

this will  hide low rate if the customer billing state not equal to the store state location,